# Making different group of sequential null data in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, grouping

I have data that contain sequential null and I want to make those sequential null data to different group

I have data like below

| group_num | days | time | useage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20200101 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 20200101 | 2 | 10 |
| 1 | 20200101 | 3 | null |
| 2 | 20200102 | 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 2 | null |
| 2 | 20200102 | 3 | null |
| 2 | 20200102 | 4 | 50 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 5 | null |
| 3 | 20200105 | 10 | null |
| 3 | 20200105 | 11 | null |
| 3 | 20200105 | 12 | 5 |

---

What I want to do in this data is that make null_group data in usage as the group.

I want to make the same null group if null data is sequential. And also I want to make different null group if null data is not sequential or have different group_num.

| group_num | days | time | useage | null_group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20200101 | 1 | 10 |  |
| 1 | 20200101 | 2 | 10 |  |
| 1 | 20200101 | 3 | null | group1 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 1 | 30 |  |
| 2 | 20200102 | 2 | null | group2 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 3 | null | group2 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 4 | 50 |  |
| 2 | 20200102 | 5 | null | group3 |
| 3 | 20200105 | 10 | null | group4 |
| 3 | 20200105 | 11 | null | group4 |
| 3 | 20200105 | 12 | 5 |  |

Or maybe make new data that only contain null data with different group.

| group_num | days | time | useage | null_group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20200101 | 3 | null | group1 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 2 | null | group2 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 3 | null | group2 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 5 | null | group3 |
| 3 | 20200105 | 10 | null | group4 |
| 3 | 20200105 | 11 | null | group4 |

null_group can be change to numeric like below

| group_num | days | time | useage | null_group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20200101 | 3 | null | 1 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 2 | null | 2 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 3 | null | 2 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 5 | null | 3 |
| 3 | 20200105 | 10 | null | 4 |
| 3 | 20200105 | 11 | null | 4 |

Can anyone help with this problem? I thought I can do this with pyspark's window function, but it didn't work very well. I think I have to use pyspark because the original data is too large handling as python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a bit complicated, but the last 2 parts are just for displaying correctly. The main logic goes like this:

1. calculate "time" difference "dt" between rows (needs to be 1 for the same "null_group")
2. generate "key" from "usage" and "dt" columns
3. use the trick to label consecutive rows (originally for pandas https://www.codeforests.com/2021/03/30/group-consecutive-rows-in-pandas/)
4. rename and manipulate labels to get desired result

Full solution:

```
w = Window.partitionBy('group_num').orderBy('time')
w_cumsum = w.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

# main logic
df_tmp = (
    df
    .withColumn('dt', F.coalesce(F.col('time') - F.lag('time').over(w), F.lit(1)))
    .withColumn('key', F.concat_ws('-', 'usage', 'dt'))
    .withColumn('prev_key', F.lag('key').over(w))
    .withColumn('diff', F.coalesce((F.col('key') != F.col('prev_key')).cast('int'), F.lit(1)))
    .withColumn('cumsum', F.sum('diff').over(w_cumsum))
    .withColumn('null_group_key',
                F.when(F.isnull('usage'), F.concat_ws('-', 'group_num', 'cumsum')).otherwise(None))
)

# map to generate required group names
df_map = (
    df_tmp
    .select('null_group_key')
    .distinct()
    .dropna()
    .sort('null_group_key')
    .withColumn('null_group', F.concat(F.lit('group'), F.monotonically_increasing_id() + F.lit(1)))
)

# rename and display as needed
(
    df_tmp
    .join(df_map, 'null_group_key', 'left')
    .fillna('', 'null_group')
    .select('group_num', 'days', 'time', 'usage', 'null_group')
    .sort('group_num', 'time')
    .show()
)
```

Comment: @KJH Glad it works. I updated the code since there was one mistake. "dt" needs to be calculated with previous row not the next one (F.lag() instead of F.lead()).